# simple_form nested json attributes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, forms

The [`Company`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/pages-app/blob/master/app/models/company.rb) model [`preferences` jsonb field](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/pages-app/blob/master/db/schema.rb):

```
Company.new.preferences
=> { display_settings: { attr1: "" }}
```

The following html [`input` field](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/pages-app/blob/master/app/views/companies/_display.html.erb) should be created with [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) tag [`simple_fields_for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#simple-fields-for)

```
<input type="text" name="company[preferences][display_settings][attr1]">
```

I am only able to render an `input` with `name="company[preferences][attr1]"` by following this [instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-inputs-for-key-value-hash-attributes) and it will persist to the database:

```
Company.last.preferences
=> { attr1: "" }
```

I am using the following `erb`:

```
<% preferences = PreferencesDecorator.new(@company.preferences["display_settings"])
  f.simple_fields_for(preferences) do |field|
    preferences.each do |key, value| %>
     <label for="<%= key %>"><%= key %></label>
     <%= field.input_field key %>
  <% end
end %>
```

Comment: Please, add code where you're generating incomplete input

Comment: @Vasilisa thanks for your comment. I added the code which is generating incomplete input.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I haven't done something like this per se, but from your link, it seems Solution 3 is easer (that of which makes use of `OpenStruct`).

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I was able to implement `solution 1` and generate <`input name="company[preferences][attr1]" />`, but I need `name="company[preferences][display_attributes][attr1]"` so that the rails controller gets the correct parameters. I will try some workaround, but could not find any explanation on how to do this with `simple_form`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested, but can you try:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :preferences, OpenStruct.new(f.object.preferences) do |ff|
  <% ff.object.to_h.each do |key, value| %>
    <% if value.is_a? Hash %>
      <%= ff.simple_fields_for key, OpenStruct.new(value) do |fff| %>
        <% fff.object.to_h.each do |key, value| %>
          <%= fff.input key, input_html: { value: value } %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= ff.input key, input_html: { value: value } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

### TODOs:

- code above only supports 2-level deep "looping" in the hash, because of explicit checking of `is_a? Hash` until the 2nd level. 3rd-level, and so on are not yet supported and therefore probably best to write a `helper` method to dynamically generate all of these input fields (however deep that hash may be).

Comment: ^ Let me know if my solution works, and if it does, I'll try to write a `helper` method for this that will support for all any-deep hashes.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio No prob. Hope it worked. If not yet, I'll test this further later after I get the time :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. It helped me find the solution. I will post the solution to this problem if authorized. I will accept your answer, if my solution will be accepted from the customer, otherwise I will need to set a bounty on the question. Thanks a lot. I wish you a good day

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Oh of course!!! Feel free to post your discovered solution :) No problem at all!

Comment: This works (I used `form.fields_for`). Now I am struggling with showing errors below the inputs. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @knagode What does the error object output to? `puts f.object.errors.messages`. Because maybe you can build up the code to generate the error messages as you go deeper into the object / hash, depending on how this output format looks like

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I can add errors manually (via `errors.add("json_settings.name", "some error")`). But I am not sure how to name them in order to show them below the input automatically.

Comment: @knagode Why not use `form.simple_fields_for` instead? I think it already includes the errors and labels.